# Creating a minimal flask/request file uploader

Tags: python, flask

I was trying to create a minimal flask server/client python movie file uploader but my client-code doesn't seem to be working properly and I'm wondering if I need more then what I have?

**Server.py**

```
from flask import Flask, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/',  methods=['GET', 'POST', 'PUT'])
def hello_world():
    file = request.files
    return(str(file))
```

> running as: **flask run**

**Uploader.py**

```
import requests

files = {'file': open("BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4")}
r = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/", files)
print(r.text)
```

> running as: python Uploader.py

However the `hello_world` method returns `ImmutableMultiDict([])`

For Debugging purposes I've used this following curl snippet which seems to work:

```
curl -i -X PUT  -F filedata=@BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4 "http://localhost:5000/"
```

and returns

```
ImmutableMultiDict([('file', <FileStorage: u'BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4' ('application/octet-stream')>)])
```

Any Idea why the `Uploader.py` fails?

Answer (score 0):

I tried example you gave us and I think I managed to find a solution.

After some digging, I found that you can [stream requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#streaming-uploads) with `requests` module:

> Requests supports streaming uploads, which allow you to send large streams or files without reading them into memory.

You just need to provide a file to be streamed and open it in read binary mode, `rb`.

*app.py*

```
from flask import Flask, request
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/',  methods=['GET', 'POST', 'PUT'])
def hello_world():
    # 'bw' is write binary mode
    with open("BigBuckBunny_320x180_flask_upload.mp4", "bw") as f:
        chunk_size = 4096
        while True:
            chunk = request.stream.read(chunk_size)
            if len(chunk) == 0:
                return 'Done'

            f.write(chunk)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

*Uploader.py*

```
import requests

# Give proper path to your file, I used mine from flask app directory
with open('BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4', 'rb') as f:
    requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/', data=f)
```

Check [this](https://blog.pelicandd.com/article/80) article.